# Overide the font Verdana on mobile platforms/browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile, fonts

Making a mobile website, for my main website. And all my code shall be W3C validated. I use Verdana as font, and any body knows that MAC/Iphone/Ipads don't have that font. So I thought what if I just overwrite the font. But what if:
One: Will the code be W3C? Answer: YES.
Two: Will it work on all mobile platforms/browsers? Answer: IDK you tell me, new in this world.

Here is the CSS code i want to use:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: jsverdana;
src             :url('fonts/verdana.ttf')
                ,url('fonts/verdana.eot'); /* IE9 */
}

body{
    background-color    :#FFFFFF;
    background-image    :url('/media/common/newbgtest.gif');
    font-family         :jsverdana,helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin              :0;
    padding             :0;
    min-width           :600px;
}
```

And yes, i did convert the font "Verdana" This is tested on Iphone 4, and Ipad 1.

Comment: Did you test it on a device?

Comment: As the text says: This is tested on Iphone 4, and Ipad 1.

Comment: Aha, missed that. :) Do you have any friend's/colleagues with Android/WinPhone/Whatever devices you can test with?

Comment: No, that is why i ask here, so the tests can be done. :)

Comment: You have checked it in Iphone .. then better let us know whether font verdana is coming or not in iphone .. if it is coming there in iphone then it will come in all mobile devices ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Different devices require different font formats, so you should use services like FontSquirrel to generate all of them (and the CSS code for using them), if you use a downloadable font (web font).

On the other hand, Microsoft has copyright on Verdana, so you would need their permission to use it as downloadable font (and even to convert it to other formats).

A more realistic approach is to try and find a suitable free font, perhaps of the fairly nice sans-serif fonts at Google Web Fonts. Or maybe just let each device that hasn’t got Verdana use its own sans-serif font instead (which is what happens when you set `font-family: Verdana, sans-serif`).

Comment: What formats should i use? And copyright is no problem. Google Web Fonts is a no go.

Comment: Why is Google Fonts a no go?

Comment: You can legally download Google web fonts, process them with FontSquirrel, and upload them onto your server. You should not do such things with Verdana without written permission from Microsoft.

Comment: There is only one way, and that is with Verdana, the permissions is no problem.